# Automatically Stop Legend from getting Cropped by Plots (R)

Tags: r, plot, graph, data-visualization, legend

I am working with the R programming language. I generated the following data:

```
 credibility_scoree = rnorm(100, 1, 0.3)
 average_recorded_height_in_study = rnorm(100, 17,3)
my_data = data.frame(credibility_scoree, average_recorded_height_in_study )
 my_data$credibility_score = ifelse(my_data$credibility_scoree>1,1,my_data$credibility_scoree)
my_data$credibility_score = my_data$credibility_score  * my_data$credibility_score 
my_data$credibility_scoree = NULL
my_data$study_number <- seq_along(my_data[,1])
my_data$adjusted_weight <- my_data$credibility_score * my_data$average_recorded_height_in_study
```

I then tried to make plots using the following library:

```
library(fitdistrplus)

 fg <- fitdist(my_data$adjusted_weight, "gamma")
 fln <- fitdist(my_data$adjusted_weight, "lnorm")
fg <- fitdist(my_data$adjusted_weight, "gamma")
 fw <- fitdist(my_data$adjusted_weight, "weibull")

 par(mfrow = c(2, 2))
 plot.legend <- c("Weibull", "lognormal", "gamma")

 denscomp(list(fw, fln, fg), legendtext = plot.legend)
qqcomp(list(fw, fln, fg), legendtext = plot.legend)
 cdfcomp(list(fw, fln, fg), legendtext = plot.legend)
 ppcomp(list(fw, fln, fg), legendtext = plot.legend)
```

[image]

As seen in these pictures, the legends are hidden by the graphs.

**Question:** Is there an automatic way to stop this from happening?

Thanks

Comment: It's weird that legends are not hidden, locate bottom right when I try your code...

Comment: Thank you! I will try to restart my R session

Comment: @ Park: Unfortunately, the legend is still not showing up correctly

Comment: By default of those function need to goes `right` but it's very strange that they go too `right`...Maybe `graphics` got wrong about `legend(x = ...)` part. Not that manual but how about using `plotstyle = "ggplot"?

Comment: @ Park: thank you for your reply! where you would add the "plotstyle = ggplot" line of code?

Comment: I want to show the plot too, so I add the code below. Would you mind to check it out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm really sorry that adding `plotstyle = "ggplot` need to be added to every line......But I think this may help you from that weird legend locations.

```
library(patchwork)
a <- denscomp(list(fw, fln, fg), legendtext = plot.legend, plotstyle = "ggplot")
b <- qqcomp(list(fw, fln, fg), legendtext = plot.legend, plotstyle = "ggplot")
c <- cdfcomp(list(fw, fln, fg), legendtext = plot.legend, plotstyle = "ggplot")
d <- ppcomp(list(fw, fln, fg), legendtext = plot.legend, plotstyle = "ggplot")

a+b+c+d
```

[image]

Comment: WOW! thank you for this! I will have to remember this library and use it more often!

Comment: after a few minutes, I will be able to accept your answer!